# Auth0 - where can I get JWT signing secret

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, auth0

I am new to Auth0 and looking to implement Auth0 with SPA for frontend and AWS Lambda for backend.

There are many tutorials on validating Auth0 JWT token using packages like `express-jwt`, `jwks-rsa` or using API gateway's Authorizer but is there a way to retrieve the Auth0 secret (tokenSecret) so I can validate it using `jwt.verify` method?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

jwt.verify(accessToken, tokenSecret, (err, decoded) => {
      tokenError = err;

      decrytedData = decoded;
    });
```

Comment: Log in to your Auth0 account.  It's in your profile.  You have to know it, you can't retrieve it.  If you could, it wouldn't be a secret any more.

Comment: I can't find the private key that validate the JWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably use the RSA256 key that Auth0 uses by default. Therefore, you do not need the (HMAC) private key, but the the RSA public key. They are also referred to as [JSON Web Key Set](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets) (JWKS).

Auth0 exposes those JWKS at the following URL:

```
https://[your_domain].auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json
```

The response will look like this:

```json
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "alg": "RS256",
            "kty": "RSA",
            "use": "sig",
            "x5c": [
                "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"
            ],
            "n": "yeNlzlub94YgerT030codqEztjfU_S6X4DbDA_iVKkjAWtYfPHDzz_sPCT1Axz6isZdf3lHpq_gYX4Sz-cbe4rjmigxUxr-FgKHQy3HeCdK6hNq9ASQvMK9LBOpXDNn7mei6RZWom4wo3CMvvsY1w8tjtfLb-yQwJPltHxShZq5-ihC9irpLI9xEBTgG12q5lGIFPhTl_7inA1PFK97LuSLnTJzW0bj096v_TMDg7pOWm_zHtF53qbVsI0e3v5nmdKXdFf9BjIARRfVrbxVxiZHjU6zL6jY5QJdh1QCmENoejj_ytspMmGW7yMRxzUqgxcAqOBpVm0b-_mW3HoBdjQ",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg",
            "x5t": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg"
        }
    ]
}
```

The important part is the `kid` and the `x5c`. Before you can `verify` your token however, you need to convert the value of `x5c` to a RSA public key in PEM format. There is a library for that, called [jwk-to-pem](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwk-to-pem).

You can use this library to convert a key to the required PEM format. Taken the example from above:

```js
const jwkToPem = require("jwk-to-pem");

const pem = jwkToPem({
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "x5c": [
        "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"
    ],
    "n": "yeNlzlub94YgerT030codqEztjfU_S6X4DbDA_iVKkjAWtYfPHDzz_sPCT1Axz6isZdf3lHpq_gYX4Sz-cbe4rjmigxUxr-FgKHQy3HeCdK6hNq9ASQvMK9LBOpXDNn7mei6RZWom4wo3CMvvsY1w8tjtfLb-yQwJPltHxShZq5-ihC9irpLI9xEBTgG12q5lGIFPhTl_7inA1PFK97LuSLnTJzW0bj096v_TMDg7pOWm_zHtF53qbVsI0e3v5nmdKXdFf9BjIARRfVrbxVxiZHjU6zL6jY5QJdh1QCmENoejj_ytspMmGW7yMRxzUqgxcAqOBpVm0b-_mW3HoBdjQ",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "kid": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg",
    "x5t": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg"
});
```

This `pem` then can be used to `verify` your token:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

jwt.verify(token, pem, (err, decoded) => {[...]});
```

Advice:

The most important advice I can give is to "cache" the PEMs. Do not do all of the steps described in this answer for every request. You have several options how you can "cache" the keys:

1. Bundle the PEMs with your Lambda deployment package (or put them directly in the code). I would not advice this, because you need to run another deployment if the keys change, but it happens rarely enough, so that this is ok-ish. The keys are public anyway, so this is also not a security issue.
2. Download the JWKS when the Lambda initialises and convert the keys to PEM format. Then store this in a "global" variable and use that across requests.
3. Put pre-computed PEMs on S3 and download on Lambda initialisation etc.

I typically do #2, but the others are also ok.

Links:

1. [Auth0 Blog: Navigating RS256 and JWKS](https://auth0.com/blog/navigating-rs256-and-jwks/)

Comment: thanks for you amazing response, I have spent hours looking for a JWT verification that did not involve using Auth0's Express SDK. Thanks again.